# Remove actionbar from a specific activity

Tags: android

I want to remove actionbar from a specific activity, i have implemented my custom theme and changed it in manifest but it has removed actionbar from all activities.

Comment: Set the theme on just the `<activity>` that you want to have no ActionBar

Comment: Thankyou very much Mike.M,now its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that should be like that, create your own or custom theme in your `Styles` and use it exactly for your `Activity` in manifest not for all activities or whole the application!

Example:

```
 <resources>
 ...
 <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffff0000</item>
   </style>
   ...
 </resources>
```

And adding it in Manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.myapp.MyActivity"
 ...
         android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
  />
```

Comment: It is very helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your theme to your particular activity, not the whole application in manifest.